# How can i work with inline_keybord and telegram?

Tags: php

i'm trying to make a bot in telegram, but i can't run the inline keyboard of telegram, or better, i can't take the response about the key pressed from the user... this is my code:

```
function in_keyboard($chatID, $text){
  $keyboard = '{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Warrior","callback_data":"data"}],[{"text":"Paladin","callback_data":"data"}],[{"text":"Assassin","callback_data":"data"}],[{"text":"Druid","callback_data":"data"}],[{"text":"Mage","callback_data":"data"}],[{"text":"Hunter","callback_data":"data"}]]}';
  $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?&chat_id=".$chatID."parse_mode=Markdown&reply_markup=".$keyboard."&text=".urlencode($text);
  file_get_contents($url);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine as it displays six inline keyboard buttons.

Next you need to handle user input. Pressing one of the buttons will result in a request send to your server. It contains JSON as POST data you can work with.
It will look like this:

```
{
   "update_id":390709664,
   "callback_query":{
      "id":"717705292376918617",
      "from":{
         "id":12345678,
         "first_name":"foo",
         "username":"someName",
         "language_code":"en"
      },
      "message":{
         "message_id":78433,
         "from":{
            "id":210575457,
            "first_name":"yourBotDisplayName",
            "username":"yourBotUsername"
         },
         "chat":{
            "id":167103785,
            "first_name":"foo",
            "username":"someName",
            "type":"private"
         },
         "date":1498825165,
         "text":"ok"
      },
      "chat_instance":"-29205973098956026374",
      "data":"data"
   }
}
```

Take any data you need (probably the `data` field), build a response and send it to the user.